# What is the reasoning behind the changes in the Facebook SDK snippet?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Old way:

```
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; 
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
```

New way:

```
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

If we look at the differences you can notice a few changes:

1. some 'hardcoded' strings are added through parameters. Why the extra effort?
2. the script element is now added explicitly before all other script tags, instead of just appending it to the `<head>` tag. Why? I could imagine to load it faster before other blocking scripts, but as they recommend to put the script at the beginning of the `<body>` it means it processed all the script tags in the header anyway? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

1. Both s and id is used in more than one place so adding them as variables makes the code shorter.
2. There may not be a head-tag. There is always a script tag because you need to put that code in a script tag.

Comment: Point two seems to be very valid. About point 1: why not `id = 'facebook-jssdk'` like the old one? Counting the `,` and spaces it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Maybe it is just a consistency thing. Having d, s and id all be the same.